# Python with Anaconda3 can't proceed the code

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

It's supposed to draw a red circle. But the code can't be proceeded

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Circle(object):

    def _int_(self , radius=3,color='blue'):
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color

    def drawCircle(self):
        plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0), radius = self.radius, fc=self.color ))
        plt.axis('scaled')
        plt.title('A red circle')
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you mean "processed"? Probably you need to have `__init__` instead of `_int_`. If that's not it, please be more specific about what's going wrong.

Comment: where are you calling `drawCircle()` method ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This code snippet is not complete, since you never even try to do anything with the class or any of the methods. Please show a complete code snippet that should draw your circle. In other words, read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two fold:

- You do not create a Class instance and hence you never call the `drawCircle` method
- Your `__init__` method is misspelled

Following is the correct working code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Circle(object):

    def __init__(self, radius=3, color='red'):
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color

    def drawCircle(self):
        plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0), radius=self.radius, fc=self.color ))
        plt.axis('scaled')
        plt.title('A red circle')
        plt.show()

circ = Circle()
circ.drawCircle()
```

[image]